Movie Las Vegas, Title something like Blue Moon Rising
I saw this movie on late night TV in the mid eighties on a local Las Vegas TV channel. 
The theme of the movie was a cowboy coming to Las Vegas to compete in Helldorado, the local rodeo. The cowboy gets in trouble and is being chased all through old Las Vegas and the surrounding area. 
It was all Las Vegas locations were they did the filming. I think the movie was circa early to mid 1930's. Maybe done in the forties, I am not sure if it was jeeps or old model t's they were wandering around in. 
I remember the title as blue moon rising, but I have never found a reference anywhere.
It may still pop up on late movies on local TV in Las Vegas. I have not seen it since the eighties. I would love to find out more abut this movie because of the old Southern Nevada scenery in it. Fremont street, Spring mountains, Red Rock Canyon and Old Highway ninety.
Maybe you remember this movie and could help me figure out what channel showed it and if it ever made it to dvd or video.

Is it Heldorado (1946)?
From IMDB:

Roy Rogers, a Nevada State Ranger Captain in charge of the Rangers
  Reclamation Service, makes a trip to Las Vegas for the annual
  Heldorado Frontier Days Festival, as he wants to help his old friend
  Gabby Whittaker who originated the idea (at least, in this film).In
  Las Vegas, Roy meets heiress Carol Randall, who has been selected as
  the Queen of the Heldorado. Roy is informed that the F.B.I. wants an
  immediate investigation of the counterfeit thousand dollar bills that
  are being passed over the gambling tables at the casino.


No, I ran across that movie recently. As far as I can tell that movie was shot in California., With a few stock shots of hoover dam.
